# What are CL contours?

Tags: terminology, notation, error-analysis, statistics

I am reading about the precise measurement of top quark mass from: http://arxiv.org/abs/1510.04483

In the second page there is this statement

> "The 68% and 95% CL contours for the indirect determination of mW and mtop from global SM red, dashed curves, respectively. For negative values of λ, the lifetime of the SM fits to electroweak precision data"

I am a noob in analysis and did not understand what CL contours mean.

Answer (score 1):

Stands for "Confidence level" contours.

Comment: While true, I think this answer would benefit from a somewhat more elaborate description.